# how do I troubleshoot Rack::Session::Cookie after decrypting nothing looks wrong with it?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid, rack

I keep getting an error when passing parameters to a POST route telling me

```
Warning! Rack::Session::Cookie data size exceeds 4K.
Warning! Rack::Session::Cookie failed to save session. Content dropped.
```

I decrypted the cookie and absolutely nothing is out of order with it... it looks exactly as it should....

```
{"session_id"=>"94a15819b3b915556c120a5e83c75bfaab83bfce555bb81e78512adabbbbe654"}
{"user"=>#<OEDApp::User _id: 58502d2d07a0ee469cc0c065, created_at: 2016-12-13 17:17:33 UTC, updated_at: 2016-12-22 18:43:48 UTC, first_name: "", last_name: "", email: "", phone_number: "", encrypted_password: "XbUAU7w3poTt8uE7OUGwJw==", access_level: "Manager", is_active: true, is_admin: true>}
{"login"=>true}
```

Is there any known bugs with Rack Session Cookies that would cause the error to fire off?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing your `User` object directly in the session. I suspect that when it gets serialized to be stored in the cookie it is referencing other objects such that the combined size of all the objects exceeds the limit.

Rather than store the entire `User` object in the session you should just store an identifier for it (e.g. the `_id` value) and query the database for the actual object in each request.

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt solve it, unfortunately im experiencing it on three separate projects in development now, i need some serious resources to fix it asap =/

Comment: A bit too late to be helpful; I came across this post because I had this message too. Maybe this helps future readers: I found out that an object that was stored in the session contained a list of entries that got very long. That clue came from printing the session object with _p session_. No bug with Rack, it was my own design error.